# i need some help in this footer is not responsive as i want

Tags: html, css

this is the code im not so good in front-end so im looking for small touches that make this footer responsive 
the links and font-awsome icons have something wrong in the mobile screen
not responsive or the position changes if the screen changed

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="margin-bottom: 0px; background-color: #f4f4f4;height:100%;">
<div>
    <hr style="border-top:3px solid #bc2f8d; float: left;margin-left: 30px; margin-top: -15px; text-align: left;"  width="30%">
    <hr style="border-top:3px solid #bc2f8d; float: right;margin-right: 30px; margin-top: -15px; text-align: right;"  width="30%">
</div>
<h3 class="text-center" style="margin-top:0;">Bahget Dar <i class="fas fa-home" style="color:#BC2F8D"></i></h3>
<h5 class="text-center" style=";color:black;">make your home best.</h5>
<h5 class="text-center" style="color: #0d0d0d"> contact us at <strong>011175697903</strong></h5>
<div class="icon-bar" style="text-align: right;width: 200px;margin-right: 120px; font-size: 25px; float: right">
    <h5 style="margin-right: 19px;">Follow us</h5>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f" style="background:#f4f4f4;color: #3B5998; "></i></a>
    <a href="https://www.instgram.com"><i class="fab fa-instagram" style="color: transparent;background:radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%);background:-webkit-radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%);background-clip: text;-webkit-background-clip: text;"></i></a>
    <a href="https://wwww.twitter.com"><i class="fab fa-twitter" style="color:#0095ff;text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc;"></i></a>
</div>

<div class="row" style="float: unset;margin-top:8px;margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 0; max-width: 200px;" >
    <div class="col-sm-4 text-left" >
        <ul style="list-style: none;">
            <li style="text-decoration: none; width:90px;margin-left: 49px;"><a style="color:black;">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li  style="width: 40px;margin-left: 49px;"><a style="color: black">Products</a></li>
            <li  style="width: 40px;margin-left: 49px;"><a style="color: black">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<h6 class="text-center" style="position: relative;margin-bottom: -34px;">Copyright &copy; <strong><a>M.Nabih</a></strong></h6>
```

[the links and fontawsome icons is not responsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLaaP.png)

Comment: For more clarity, Please create fiddle or pen for the same.

Comment: just look at the picture and u will understand me

Answer (score 0):

please looking at this article https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp which will help you to understand responsive design, particularly using percentages for widths and margins.

I fixed your code, which should now respond as you wanted, the font awesome icons were not showing because of the class names.

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="margin-bottom: 0px; background-color: 
#f4f4f4;height:100%;">
<div>
<hr style="border-top:3px solid #bc2f8d; float: left;margin-left: 30px; 
 margin-top: -15px; text-align: left;"  width="30%">
<hr style="border-top:3px solid #bc2f8d; float: right;margin-right: 30px; 
 margin-top: -15px; text-align: right;"  width="30%">
</div>
<h3 class="text-center" style="margin-top:0;">Bahget Dar <i class="fa fa-home" style="color:#BC2F8D"></i></h3>
<h5 class="text-center" style=";color:black;">make your home best.</h5>
<h5 class="text-center" style="color: #0d0d0d"> contact us at 
<strong>01111111111</strong></h5>
<div class="icon-bar" style="text-align: right;width: 49%;margin-right: 8%; font-size: 25px; float: right">
 <h5 style="margin-right: 12px;">Follow us</h5>
 <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook-f" style="background:#f4f4f4;color: #3B5998; "></i></a>
 <a href="https://www.instgram.com"><i class="fa fa-instagram" style="color: transparent;background:radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%);background:-webkit-radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%);background-clip: text;-webkit-background-clip: text;"></i></a>
   <a href="https://wwww.twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter" style="color:#0095ff;text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc;"></i></a>
  </div>

   <div class="row" style="float: unset;margin-top:8px;margin-left: 1%; margin-right: 0; max-width: 49%;min-width: 130px;" >
    <div class="col-sm-4 text-left" >
    <ul style="list-style: none;padding-left: 0px;">
        <li style="text-decoration: none; margin-left: 20%;"><a style="color:black;">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li  style=" margin-left: 20%;"><a style="color: black">Products</a> 
        </li>
        <li  style=" margin-left: 20%;"><a style="color: black">About</a> 
        </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
    <h6 class="text-center" style="position: relative;margin-bottom: -34px;">Copyright &copy; <strong><a>M.Nabih</a></strong></h6>
```